# When would a client send a HTTP HEAD request?

Tags: http, browser, httprequest

As I understand, a HTTP HEAD request is the same as a HTTP GET request but the client only wants the metadata (i.e the usual response it would get from a GET request but without the message body).

What I'm struggling to understand is when would the browser request this? Is it triggered by a user action or some background work of the browser to work out what is on a webpage?

Comment: A browser wouldn't. It's something an application on the client side would do.

Comment: @Rob so browsers typically don't ever send HEAD requests? i.e it's something a specific/custom http client would do?

Comment: Yes. That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will send the `HEAD` method only if the `XMLHttpRequest` object is used.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('HEAD', 'url');
```